# Extjs issue with PagingToolbar - same data on the next page

Tags: javascript, extjs

There are so many issues I found about different problems with grid paging but still can't find the answer to mine.

I want to load some data from googleapis to extjs grid with ability of paging.

Let say we can query Google JSON API using the following link.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?fields=totalItems,items(id,volumeInfo/title,volumeInfo/subtitle,volumeInfo/authors,volumeInfo/publishedDate,volumeInfo/description,volumeInfo/imageLinks)&q=Neuromarketing&maxResults=40&startIndex=0
```

As you can see, I can query as much records per time as 'maxResults' and from the 'startIndex' position.

The short example of json is

```
{
 "totalItems": 298,
 "items": [
  {
    ..
```

First, I've defined a Model and a Store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.Book', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id'},
        {name: 'publishedDate', mapping: 'volumeInfo.publishedDate'},
        {name: 'title', mapping: 'volumeInfo.title'}
    ]
});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.Books', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'MyApp.view.main.Book',
    buffered: true,
    pageSize: 15,
    alias: 'store.books',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?fields=totalItems,items(id,volumeInfo/title,volumeInfo/subtitle,volumeInfo/authors,volumeInfo/publishedDate,volumeInfo/description,volumeInfo/imageLinks)',
        extraParams: {
            q : 'Javascript',
            maxResults : 15,
            startIndex : 0
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items',
            totalProperty: 'totalItems'
        }
    }
});
```

Second, I've defined a View

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.view.main.MainModel'
    ],

    xtype: 'app-main',

    controller: 'main',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'main'
    },

    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },

    items: [
    {
        region: 'center',
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        reference: 'tabPanel',
        items:[
        {
            title: 'Result',
            reference: 'tabPanelResultTab',
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'grid',
                reference: 'grid',
                title: 'Books',
                dockedItems: [{
                    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                    bind: {
                        store: '{summary}'
                    },
                    dock: 'bottom',
                    displayInfo: true
                }],
                bind: {
                    store: '{summary}'
                },
                columns: [
                    { text: 'Google ID',  dataIndex: 'id', flex: 1 },
                    { text: 'Title', dataIndex: 'title', flex: 4 },
                    { text: 'Published Date', dataIndex: 'publishedDate', flex: 1}
                ]
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
```

Third, I've defined ViewModel

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.MainModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.view.main.Books'
    ],

    alias: 'viewmodel.main',

    data: {
        name: 'MyApp'
    },

    stores: {
        summary: {
            type: 'books'
        }
    }
});
```

So now, when I click next page on pagingtoolbar, the loading image pops up, then loads exact the same data on the 2nd page I saw on the 1st page. I still don't understand, how to tell PagingToolbar to query from next 'startIndex'. Is it possible to change 'start' and 'limit' variables to my 'startIndex' and maxResults'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can configure it at the proxy level. See [startParam](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/ext/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-startParam) and [limitParam](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/ext/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-limitParam).

Comment: Thank you! I've added suggested parameters to my Store at the proxy level, but it seems nothing changed, the 2nd page is still shows me the content of the 1st.

Comment: These are not store config options. These are **proxy** config options.

Comment: I guess I figured this out, there is no need to send 'maxResults' and 'startIndex' as extraParams anymore. Now it works fine, thank you!